# What should I do if an action depend on another async action in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Sorry for my English, I hope you can understand me.

I use `redux-thunk` for async actions.

```
// actionA.js
export function actionA() {
  return fetch('api call')
           .then((data) => ({
             type: 'actionA',
             data: data
           }))
}

// reducer.js
export function reducer(state, action) {
  ...
  if(action.type === 'actionA') {
    return {
      ...,
      dataA: action.data,
      ...
    };
  }
}

// actionB.js
export function actionB() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if(!getState().dataA) {
      dispatch(actionA());
    }
    doSomethingWithDataA(getState().dataA);
  };
}
```

In some cases, I only need to dispatch `actionA` without dispatching `actionB`. But when I dispatching `actionB`, `actionB` will use `dataA`, and `dataA` is created by `actionA`. So in `actionB`, I will check if there is `dataA` in `Store`, if not, I will dispatch `actionA` first. But `actionA` is an async action, I can not get when `actionA` is done.
So how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to do something when `dataA` is ready and `actionB` had happened. You can do it using [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html)

```
function myMiddleware() {
    return store => next => action => {
        const dataA = store.getState().dataA;
        if(store.getState().dataA && action.type === 'actionB') {
            doSomethingWithDataA(dataA);
        }
    };
}
```

Then your actionB turns into the following

```
function lazyFetchDataA() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if(!getState().dataA) {
            return dispatch(actionA());
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }
}

export function actionB() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
       lazyFetchDataA().then(() => dispatch({type: 'actionB'}))
    }   
}
```

It looks difficult, but now you have little pieces of code in proper places that do your thing.

Probably you don't have to do such a difficult thing if you provide more information what your `doSomethingWithDataA` is, I would give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help, note I will be using the [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) polyfill to return a promise for aysnc request.

```
function actionA(dataA) {
  return {
    type: 'actionA',
    data: dataA
  };
}


export function actionB() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if(!getState().dataA) {
      return fetch('api call')
          .then((data) => {
            dispatch(actionA(data))
          })
          .catch((error) => {// handle error})
    }
    return doSomethingWithDataA(getState().dataA);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually in `fetchDateFromServer()` of `actionA`, I just use  fetch polyfill. And the problem is in some cases, I only need to dispatch `actionA` without dispatching `actionB`.